# Subscribing to event in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I have 2 different Javascript files.

hexagon.js

```
  function HexagonGrid(canvasId, radius) {
this.radius = radius;

this.height = Math.sqrt(3) * radius;
this.width = 2 * radius;
this.side = (3 / 2) * radius;

this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

this.canvasOriginX = 0;
this.canvasOriginY = 0;

this.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.clickEvent.bind(this), false);

this.hexGridList = {};
};

  HexagonGrid.prototype.clickEvent = function (e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX;
    var mouseY = e.pageY;

    var localX = mouseX - this.canvasOriginX;
    var localY = mouseY - this.canvasOriginY;

    **var tile = this.getSelectedTile(localX, localY);**

    if (tile.column >= 0 && tile.row >= 0) {

    //find
    //this.hexGridList['row' + tile.row + 'column' + tile.column]. 

    var drawy = tile.column % 2 == 0 ? (tile.row * this.height) + this.canvasOriginY + 6 : (tile.row * this.height) + this.canvasOriginY + 6 + (this.height / 2);
        var drawx = (tile.column * this.side) + this.canvasOriginX;

        this.drawHex(drawx, drawy - 6, "rgba(110,110,70,0.3)", "");
    } 
};
```

Mainpage.js

```
    <script src="Hexagon.js"></script>
     var hexagonGrid = new HexagonGrid("HexCanvas", 50);
```

So, my mainpage is the page that is running, and I am trying to return the tile on the bolded line in hexagon.js back to mainpage.js on mouse click. How do I get the tile object from hexagon.js to the mainpage.js page on mouse click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback.

Create a function in main to handle the event

```
function doSomethingWhenHexagonIsClicked(hg, tile) {
    ...
}
```

Add a function property to your HexagonGrid, perhaps in the constructor

```
function HexagonGrid(canvasId, radius, callback) {
    ...
    this.callback = callback
    ...
}
```

And modify the call in main:

```
var hexagonGrid = new HexagonGrid("HexCanvas", 50, doSomethingWhenHexagonIsClicked);
```

Or just set it as a property

```
hexagonGrid = doSomethingWhenHexagonIsClicked;
```

And then modify your clickEvent

```
HexagonGrid.prototype.clickEvent = function (e) {
    ...
    var tile = this.getSelectedTile(localX, localY);
    if (this.callback) {
        this.callback(this, tile);
    }
    ...
}
```

A simple example (jQuery version commented out)

```js
function handleFoo() {
    console.log("Callback called");
}

Foo.prototype.clickEvent = function(e) {
    if (this.callback) {
        this.callback();
    }
}

function Foo(id, callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
    //$(id).on('click', this.clickEvent.bind(this));
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', this.clickEvent.bind(this), false);
}

var foo;
function init() {
    //foo = new Foo('#button', handleFoo);
    foo = new Foo('button', handleFoo);
}

//$(document).ready(init);
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );
```

```html
<!-- script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script -->
<body>
<form name="test">
<input id="button" type="button" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly.